# Regex expression using ${}

Tags: regex

I can't get this regex to work:

```
let varString = 'I am writing a ${varHere}';
let myKey = 'varHere';

pString = pString.replace(new RegExp(`\${${myKey}}`, 'g'), 'test');
```

But this works:

```
let varString = 'I am writing a ${varHere}';
let myKey = 'varHere';

pString = pString.replace(new RegExp(`{${myKey}}`, 'g'), 'test');
// pString = 'I am writing a $test';
```

It is just the `$` that is a problem.

Comment: Do you want ``.replace(new RegExp(`\\\${${myKey}}`, 'g'), 'test')``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not interpolating your string correctly:

```
console.log(`\$\{${myKey}\}`);
```

will get you `${varHere}`. Putting this in the RegExp, it will try to match $ (End of line) for {varhere} number of times, which is, of course, an invalid regular expression. You need to escape your expression to get the desired result:

```
new RegExp(`\\\$\\\{${myKey}\\\}`, 'g')
```

Instead, since you're not really in need of a RegExp here, you could also use the simpler string replace:

```
pString = varString.replace(`\$\{${myKey}\}`, 'test');
```

Comment: It's not mandatory to escape the curly brackets in this case. (Both in JS and in the regex)